# Регулярное выражение для разделения ячеек в xml средствами php

Tags: php, xml, pcre

Стоит задача разбить строку средствами php и записать все найденные подстроки (ячейки) в массив по порядку.
Строка выглядит к примеру так -

```
<c r="C5" s="4" t="s"><v>2</v></c><c r="D5" s="5"/><c r="E5" s="5" t="s"><v>3</v></c>
```

А разбить необходимо по ячейкам т.е по тегу `<c>`.
Сложность в том, что тег может быть как парным так и одиночным (как и показано в примере).
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Если у вас там валидный XML, то https://www.php.net/manual/ru/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Comment: Наверно неправильно сформулировал мысль. Целью является записать  в массив всё вместе с тегами <c>....</c>-0й эл-т, <c ... />-1й эл-т ит.д. Ну и крайне не хотелось бы подключать библиотеки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ Bloom'а довольно странен.
Но я вроде решил задачку: `preg_match_all("#<c.+?/(>|c>)#", $__string, $match);`
Все равно всем спасибо за небезразличие.

Comment: Ну к примеру, если вам нужно искать только тег, без значений, то как минимум так: `<c.+?(?:/>|c>)`, нежели как вы выплевывать и группы, непонятно зачем... А вот если хотите искать и то и другое, это уже другой вопрос. Ну это я просто ваше решение обернул, ибо проверить не на чем сейчас, но думаю это работать должно.

Comment: Да,  соглашусь с вами по поводу `?:` собственно вроде и карман  не нужен

Comment: [`<c.+?/c?>`](https://regex101.com/r/UHYQxl/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ft='<c r="C5" s="4" t="s"><v>2</v></c><c r="D5" s="5"/><c r="E5" s="5" t="s"><v>3</v></c>';


 preg_match_all("/<[^>]+>|[^<>]+/", $ft, $arr);
   print_r($arr);
```

Comment: воу, воу.... Это вообще нерабочий пример полностью, а точнее рабочий на все что ему хочется видеть До или после за или перед `<>`, а то и вообще `_-_` Да что угодно.... А если вдруг появились аттрубиты, то он сломается или покажет всю длину строки....

Comment: да, я так не силён в регулярках, по этому просто распарсил так.

Comment: Дак зачем писать, если это не решает задачу..., или вы не уверены, ответ следует удалить.

Comment: показал каким инстр. воспользоваться, яж не знаю его уровень, за то он сам нашёл ответ